# how to move Label away from x axis in Recharts

Tags: recharts

I could not move the Label down away (e.g. 30px) from x axis although margin and padding were used.

```
       <XAxis
          dataKey="week_of_year"
          tick={{ fontSize: '12px' }}
       >
          <Label
            position='insideBottom'
            offset={10}
            value="Week of year"
            style={{ fontSize: '80%', fill: 'black', padding: '100px' }}
          />
        </XAxis>
```

Your suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dx` and `dy` properties of `<Label />`

For example:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your comments, but dx and dy do not help. Offset={-5} alone is better for my case.